# Calculating string array characters with threads

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

To start with ,I have a String Array in my main class

I want to complete the same task using 2 threads.

Question 1: Can I pass the whole string array to the threads or just String[0],String[2] etc?

Question 2: I'm really confused as to how to read the strings so I can avoid 2 threads reading the same string

Question 3: I have a class multiThreaded.multiThreadedRunnable

Should I merge the 2 files into 1 ,or can I keep working with 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quistion 1,2: Pass the whole array, and range e.g

```
public void doIt(String[] arr, int beging, int end){
     for(int i = begin; i < end; i++){
          //place your implementation
     }
}
```

Question 3: You don't need to merge them

If you use synchronized method you will not see the difference because the method will be locked and other methods need to wait. Make `count` -  `volatile` to have the latest value `count` and remove `synchronized` from the method

Comment: add "hugeString" and "range" - (begin and end) as instance variable. In 'multiThreadedRunnable' initialize them. Place "doIt" method in 'threadRunnable' and have fun!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is separate the jobs to the threads. For example you have one thread calculate from zero to hugeString.size()/2 and the other from middle to end and then add the results. Reading something with multiple threads is thread safe but changing something is not.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to implement is called a *Farm*; it's a basic [algoritmic skeleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_skeleton) which model parallel indipendent computation, in your case on a shared data structure (commonly called Data Parallel Computation).

You should keep the two classes separated, as the first one act as a Emitter/Collector and the second one is the implementation of the Worker (which can in general be more than just 2).

As for the "overlapping" problem, you should pass the string array AND two indices, the starting point and the ending point, to each worker. This must be done by the Emitter part, while the Collector part (after the join() calls) should gather the data received by the workers and "accumulate" the result to get the total count.

By the way, there are frameworks that allow you to do this in a much simpler way than code everything by hand. For java I know of [Skandium](https://github.com/mleyton/Skandium), but I'm sure there are others

Have a look at this [tutorial](http://calvados.di.unipi.it/dokuwiki/doku.php/ffnamespace:tutorial) (it's for a C/C++ algoritmic skeleton framework, but the basic idea is the same)